# Errors while signing apk with proguard

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am trying to generate a signed apk with proguard ON. I have the following line the build.gradle for the proguard

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
```

But while generating the signed apk, I get the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Unable to compute hash of D:\project_name\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar
```

The app builds fine but the issue is only while signing the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into build.gradle file

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

And add below line into the 'proguard-project.txt'

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

For more details go to the below links [Link](https://github.com/maheshwarLigade/android-proguard-snippets)

Comment: This is clearly not a valid answer since minifyEnabled -false will disable the proguard.

Comment: @rootpanthera  look into this now, I changed

Comment: Thanks for replying. 

I changed the line to

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

and created a proguard-rules.txt in the root directory of project and added the rules that you mentioned. I am still getting the same error.